# login button from the sign up page takes directly to MainActivity without actually loging in

Tags: android, firebase

From the SignUp activity I have this code:

```
 regToLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

inside my login activity, I have these lines of code:

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
            finish();
```

I added these lines to make sure that the user remains logged in even if he leaves the app. However, it caused a problem. Whenever I signup for a new user and hit login button(from the signup activity) it directly sends me to the Home activity without logging in.(it skips the login activity)

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you signed the user to database or firebase you can simply write that:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1 (Recommended)

This is happening because auth.getCurrentUser() is not null. I've faced the same problem before. You need to call the following code:

```java
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

#### Method 2

If you are in development mode and need a quick and temporary workaround, go to your app's info and **Clear Storage**.